# Expand current VBA search code across all sheets in excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, search, worksheet

I have found plenty of answers to my problem, but I was unable due to my inexperience to re-apply other solutions to my code, unfortunately.

What I'm trying to accomplish is use my current working code, in which I am entering a string I want to search for within a sheet, and expand it over other sheets, too.

On a side note, I am not sure if "only expanding" my current code to other sheets would even be enough (I guess not), without adding some kind of loop to make sure I don't get stuck at the last sheet after the first successful search?

Either way, what I've tried hasn't worked. But it also hasn't caused any errors or changes. The code still works as it did before I tried to expand it to multiple sheets.

```
    Private Sub suchbutton_Click()

    Dim fullstring As String, searchstring As String
    Dim partfound As String, locationfound As String, partqtyinfound As String
    Dim partnotein As String, partspecialin As String, lastbin As String
    Dim columnpart As String, columnlocation As String, lineqtydetail As String
    Dim quickbin2 As String
    Dim ergebnis As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lenght_a As Long, lenght_b As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("INPUT-1", "SINGLE-2", "SINGLE-3")) 'changed from Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT-1")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("INPUT-1", "SINGLE-2", "SINGLE-3")) 'added this

    lastbin = "A"
    columnlocation = "B"
    quickbin2 = "C"
    columnpart = "L"
    partqtyinfound = "M"
    lineqtydetail = "N"
    partnotein = "O"
    partspecialin = "P"
    
    lenght_a = Len(limiter_a)
    lenght_b = Len(limiter_b)
    
    fullstring = SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value
    
    openPos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_a)
    closePos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_b)
   
    If openPos > "0" And closePos > "0" Then
    
        searchstring = Mid(fullstring, openPos + lenght_a, closePos - openPos - lenght_b)
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        
            If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
                booFound = True
                
                SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ws.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ws.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ws.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ws.Range(lastbin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ws.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value & Chr(vbKeySpace) & "PCS" & " - " & ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value & vbCrLf & ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value & vbCrLf & "##################" & vbCrLf & SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail
                SucheTeilenummer.quickbin2 = ws.Range(quickbin2 & j).Value
                
            End If
            
        Next j
        
    Else
        searchstring = "Keine Limiter gefunden"
    End If
        
    If Not booFound Then
        SucheTeilenummer.partfound = searchstring
        emptySucheForm
    End If

    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value = ""
    fullstring = ""
    ergebnis = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.SetFocus
    
    Next 'tried closing here

    End Sub
```

Comment: You _really_ should add `Option Explicit` at the top of each module. _Tools ~ Options ~ Require Variable Declaration_ will do it automatically going forward.  That said - you should add `Dim ws as Worksheet`  and define `limiter_a` and `limiter_b` - they're both empty variants.  What are they meant to be?

Comment: Also that first `ws =` line isn't needed.  Values are passed to it in the `For Each ws ...` loop.

Comment: Would there only be none or 1 result from the search ?

Comment: Every reference will need the Object Qualifier, if search multiple sheets. `If ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks for the help. Limiter_a and _b are defined as certain positions to focus on within the string that is entered to the search field, it's written in a different Public Sub that I hadn't included in this post.

Comment: @CDP1802 Hi. There should be at least 1 result, but there will also often be more than 1 result for the searched for string. Example, if I type in the searchword "Hat", I'll get the result for the Hat with the blue ribbon, but also one for a Hat with a red ribbon. This is currently working with this code. But the Hat with the red ribbon could be on sheet 3 of 6.

Comment: @Blackcat I'll try to apply what you posted, thank you.

Comment: Is `SucheTeilenummer.partfound` a text box ? If so, how will you show multiple search results ?

Comment: @CDP1802 SucheTeilenummer.partfound is a text box, yes. But the multiple values I need are within SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail, which is why it was merged the way it is. Then there used to be an Exit For at the end which was deleted, this kept the search going on.

Comment: @CDP1802 Here's a quote for better understanding the previous changes made: "I'm not familiar with the German language in your code, but you are right, that it is your For Next loop that stops looking for additional lines that match.

I would create a boolean variable (eg booFOUND) to mark as True when a matching entry is found and then use it to set the value of your ergebnis string after completing the loop."

Comment: @Blackcat Sorry, but could you please elaborate. Are you saying I need to set the `If ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then` to which other references? I wasn't able to get this one. Thank you. Currently I am getting the error that this part of the code is faulty `lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I suggest add `ws.` to `Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then` to be sure of the correct sheet. To error if use `Option Explicit` (?) lastRow also must be defined.